Download video on Whatsapp
I have just received a video from a customer, via Whatsapp, and I'd like to download it.
There was no automatic download, configured on my Whatsapp, and now, even after having configured it, this has not performed the download.
The video is quite large, and forwarding it to mail or teams is also not an option.
When I start the "Samsung My Files" app, I arrive inside some subdirectory I can't get out of.
So, basically:

How can I download a video from a Whatsapp on my smartphone?
When downloaded on my smartphone, where is it?
When plugging my smartphone into my PC, I don't see my smartphone. How to configure that?

I'm working with a Samsung Galaxy A51
Thanks in advance

They're located in
Internal Storage/Android/media/com.whatsapp/WhatsApp/Media/WhatsApp Video/

Sort the folder by "newest" and scroll to find the video, you should find it.

Lemme know in comments if you have any problem.
